# Traversing the list to find start and end point

Tags: python

z and x are two list containing sensor reading and corresponding time  of each sensor reading. From this two list , i need to find the starting point(sensor value begins to change continuously ) of the sensor reading and ending point(sensor value stops changing continuously). Here i am traversing the list and subtracting the consecutive values and try to identify the starting point and also almost similar logic to find the ending point by traversing the list backwards. But due to little noises in the sensor reading, the output is incorrect every time. i have attached the graph here and  one can see from the graph that staring position and ending position are deviating (+/- 30 mm)   Is there any better way than this like using differentiation or other concepts to get the starting and ending reading with imp? Any links or concept overview would be helpful for me.

[Output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JU0X.png)

```
def min_distance(self, z, x):


    count = 0
    i =  0
    while count<2 and (i+1) !=len(z):
        if abs(z[i] - z[i+1]) >= 1:  
            count += 1
        i+=1

    min_value = z[i+2] 
    min_time = x[i+2]

    return min_value,min_time




 def max_distance(self,z,x):

    count = 0
    j =  5
    while count<2 and j!=len(z):
        if (abs(z[-j] - z[-j-5]) - abs(z[-j] - z[-j+2])) >=1.5 :
            count +=1
        j+=1

    max_value = z[-j+15]
    max_time = x[-j+15]

    return max_value,max_time
```

Comment: You'll need to decide what level of change is 'noise' and what is required to be detected as 'changed reading'. You can then use that threshold when iterating over your list looking at differences. If you find that the program is still detecting 'noise', then your threshold is wrong

Comment: the problem  is  , it is difficult to find the level of noise here ( it changes everytime). i would like to know if there is any better way instead of iterating my list like using differentiation or some other concepts

Comment: It all depends on your situation. There are lots of things that you could consider - is there always going to be a change in the signal, or is this intended to detect its presence too? Is the change always the same height? How much noise is too much? What do you expect it to do if there is a change, but the noise is so big that it's the same strength as the change in signal?

Comment: i am a beginner and sorry to say that it is very difficult to follow you. Can you please tell me is there any other approach that can be used to find starting and ending point , without  considering the noise.

Comment: There may be lots of approaches, but you'll still need to have answers to the bits I just asked

Comment: okay .. then i try to answer your questions. No the signal is not going to change all the time. No this is not intended to detect the presense of noise. Nop the change is not always the same height. Here the deviation( difference between actual and obtained reading) should not be greater than 1 mm

Comment: There is a lot of work in the field of signal processing in general and edge-detection in particular. Concepts that you might find useful or interesting include low-pass filtering, edge-detection, and debouncing. In general, you will need a good understanding of the environment you are operating in and your desired outcome to apply these ideas with good results - you will need to know how much noise you can expect (which is plainly not 1mm), and you will need to decide what sort of tolerance you have for false-positives and false-negatives.

Comment: oh, and differentiation will not help you. Integration might, but you're probably better off with low-pass filtering if you're going to go in that direction